# NodeJS File Statistics

Tags: node.js, fs

I don't know if this is a valid question but is there a documentation out there describing each property from the result of `fs.stat()` in nodejs. Because I am trying to find the meaning of each of those properties but no luck.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked in the source code? https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js

Comment: Surprising this still isn't documented... you shouldn't have to look in the source code to grasp the meaning of a returned object's properties.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Comments in the [node_file.cc source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/f0ce98441ff7315e6a6c268dabcec58fc37da926/src/node_file.cc#L304-L343) that builds the `stat` object (`BuildsStatsObject` function) may conveniently help you out with this. In summary for reference:

- `dev` : ID of device containing file
- `ino` : inode number
- `mode` : protection
- `nlink` : number of hard links
- `uid` : user ID of owner
- `gid` : group ID of owner
- `rdev` : device ID (if special file)
- `size` : total size, in bytes
- `atime` - time of last access
- `mtime` - time of last modification
- `ctime` - time of last status change

and if POSIX

- `blksize` : blocksize for filesystem I/O
- `blocks` : number of blocks allocated

Comment: The source of node_file.cc has been modified in the meanwhile with the remotion of the comments: to see the version of the 2nd of august 2012 (with the comments) go to https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/f0ce98441ff7315e6a6c268dabcec58fc37da926/src/node_file.cc

Comment: Thanks @niconic, I've updated the link with the relevant code highlighted.